# Print Label text from NSDictionary which have JSON Object

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, json, uilabel

my json file looks like this

```
[{"id":"1","category":"New Category1","title":"New Product2","description":"Please type a description1","imgurl":"http:\/\/s.wordpress.org\/about\/images\/wordpress-logo-notext-bg.png","spectitle":"Specification","specvalue":"Value"},{"id":"2","category":"Mobile","title":"Samsung","description":"Please type a description","imgurl":"http:\/\/s.wordpress.org\/about\/images\/wordpress-logo-notext-bg.png","spectitle":"Price","specvalue":"100$"}]
```

and i have 4 label that have to print id,category,title,description in individual labels.I have successfully parsed entire json object and printed in a single label.I need to display all the json Object with corresponding category  to corresponding label.

```
NSString *labelstring =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[json objectAtIndex:0]];
label1.text=[NSString stringwithformat: objectForKey:@"id"]; 
 label2.text=[NSString stringwithformat:objectForKey:@"category"];
 label3.text=[NSString stringwithformat:objectForKey:@"title"];  
 label4.text=[NSString stringwithformat:objectForKey:@"description"];
```

here json is a variable for NSArray with have URL info and those things...But if i try to get individual value i can't get it..Guidance please...

Comment: How do you assign `json` variable? Do you use a json parser? Which one?

Comment: Those stringWithFormat: calls are superfluous... don't you realize?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you showing your real code? `[NSString stringwithformat:objectForKey:@"id"];` is invalid syntax. Don't you get any errors?

The correct code:

```
// ??? NSString *labelstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[json objectAtIndex:0]];
NSDictionary *dict = [json objectAtIndex:0];
label1.text = [dict valueForKey:@"id"]; 
label2.text = [dict valueForKey:@"category"];
label3.text = [dict valueForKey:@"title"];  
label4.text = [dict valueForKey:@"description"];
```

---

**Edit:** I don't know if you parse your JSON in the correct way, so here is it, too:

```
NSData *jsonData = ...
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
```

Answer (score 5):

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://advantixcrm.com/prj/mitech/index.php/api/appconfig/Mg"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

    NSError *err;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];

    NSArray *array=[jsonArray objectForKey:@"info"];

    for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
        _label.text = [[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"restaurant_location"]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the json that way, you need to decode it into an `NSDictionary` then you can use it the way you're trying to in the latter half:

```
label1.text = [NSString stringwithFormat:@"%@", [json objectForKey:@"id"]];
```

Or if you simply need the text that is under the `"id"` tag in json you can do:

```
label1.text = [json objectForKey:@"id"];
```